# ActiveRecord: sanitising dynamic values within `select` or `order` calls

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Dynamic values are sanitised automatically when correctly passed into a `where` statement, so given `query = "Batman"`:

`where('heroes.alias % :query', :query => query)`

However, neither `select` nor `order` provide a like syntax leaving us with:

`select("heroes.* SIMILARITY(heroes.alias, '#{query}') AS similarity")`

and

`order("SIMILARITY(heroes.alias, '#{query}' ASC")`

Which requires manual sanitising of the `query` var which if done incorrectly can leave one open to SQL injection - my question then is, does anyone have a more robust solution that is less reliant on manual sanitising?

Answer (score -1):

Unlike where clause, whose conditions string will get passed to database as is and get executed, select statement and order clause actually do not involve any logic part will be executed on the database end, so sanitation is not necessary here. Anything passed in will be handled on ORM later first before sent to database. The worse case will give you a illegal sql.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's not true. It's trivial to create a scenario by which a psql syntax exception is raised (`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement`) which is certainly worse that a not found. See https://gist.github.com/scepticalcat/25713f2969287418e55401f563c74413

Comment: @BrightBlue you're right on going into the details, but the point still hold. What you're getting here is a illegal sql that won't leak or damage your data. This is generally not considered as a security risk, I've edited my answer to be more precise.

Comment: That is completely untrue. The query could be made to retrieve arbitrary data from any table in the database, eg if in the select example query was something like `"'), some_table.* from heroes inner join some_table -- "`

Comment: @FrederickCheung I think you're constructing raw sql while the question here is about query interface. What you list there will be passed in as a single attribute to look for on the model and get rejected, before translated into actual sql

Comment: Then this would contradict to what I've been believing, I'll try it too tomorrow, what db are you using?

Comment: @miushock :: Allowing user input to cause a PG exception and rescuing from that is not what I would consider an acceptable alternative to even naively sanitising the data. That's also assuming that a more sophisticated attempt than the one I cobbled together couldn't still do damage. As the error returned by my example is already a PG error, you're assumption that it is rejected before being translated to SQL is incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

Since all values that you want be passed are columns of a table i'd sanitize them by checking against the attribute list of the model like this:

```
sort_by = YourModel.attribute_names.include?(query) ? query : 'some_fallback_column'
```

Comment: The query param that is being passed in wouldn't be a database column. Take the case above where `query` would be user input to be assessed for trigram similarity against the `alias` database column.